# Putting a UserControl inside of a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contextmenu

I have a `UserControl` that is basically set up to look like a `ContextMenu`. Example below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProj.Views.ContextMenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="450" Width="172">
    <StackPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="Set" Command="{Binding SetModeCmd}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../Images/set.ico" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Views...">
            <MenuItem Header="Open..." />
            <MenuItem Header="Save..." />
            <MenuItem Header="Factory Default" />
        </MenuItem>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now, I have a main `Window` with a `ContentControl`. I want the `ContentControl` to display my `UserControl` instead of a normal `ContextMenu`. I tried putting my control inside of the `ContextMenu` itself, but none of the menu items are clickable because the `ContextMenu` always has focus.

Here's the relevant part in my main window:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MainView}">
    <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <views:ContextMenuView /> <!-- trying to put my usercontrol here -->
        </ContextMenu>
    </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
</ContentControl>
```

Edit: Entire .xaml for the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProj.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestProj.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="737.239" Width="1455.446"
             Name="OnyxControl">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainView}" Focusable="True">
            <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <views:ContextMenuView />
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProj.Views.ContextMenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="57.2" Width="172"
             Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel>
        <MenuItem Header="Pan" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Views...">
            <MenuItem Header="Open..." />
            <MenuItem Header="Save..." />
            <MenuItem Header="Factory Default" />
        </MenuItem>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Yes. Why not just try it? If you do it the way you have it, you'll get MenuItem selection visuals when you mouse over it, because it will be placed inside a conventional MenuItem. You can avoid that by putting it in the ContextMenu's template (but be sure to give your control an opaque background): `<ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu"><local:MyControl /></...`

Comment: You can also put it in the control template of a menu item in the context menu. Or put it in the Header property  of a menu item in the context menu. Lots of options.

Comment: Updated my post. Putting it in a control template like you suggested works great except for menu items with sub menu items.

Comment: Sounds like might want `<MenuItem.Header><views:ContextMenuView />...` in that case.

Comment: Tried that and putting it in a menu item's control template as well. Same behavior for both.

Comment: I don't get the same behavior at all. If I put it in the header, the submenu for that menu item works fine. Can you share your menu XAML for when you put the usercontrol in the menuitem's header, with submenu?

Comment: Done. Added a gif to show the behavior as well.

Comment: Where does the "Views..." submenu come from?

Comment: If you check the beginning of my post in my `UserControl` xaml, I edited it and put it there.

Comment: OK, so it works when I try it. And you're telling me it doesn't work when you try it. But instead of showing me the actual XAML that doesn't work for you, you want me to copy and paste various snippets of unknown provenance from various places in your question, and then *try to guess* how to put them together to get it to demonstrate the behavior you say you're seeing, though of course I have zero reason to believe any of it bears any resemblance at all to the XAML that's not working. All this because you don't feel like using copy and paste. I'm sorry, but life is much too short for that.

Comment: Try putting in a plain Label rather than the usercontrol, maybe there's something the usercontrol is doing. It's a longshot but without seeing the XAML, it's all I've got.

Comment: Well, I updated it again and put the entire xaml for my main window and the user control. As I said in a previous comment, I also tried using the control template and it gives the same behavior with sub-menus.

Comment: OK, now I understand. Thank you for sharing the actual XAML. I had no idea what you were doing. But you can't do that: You can't put a menu item inside a usercontrol inside the header of another menu item, and expect it to behave like a menu item belonging to the actual menu. If you want to share a ContextMenu, create it as a resource. Is that the underlying goal here, to re-use a ContextMenu definition?

Comment: Damn. The control template was so close too. Thanks for the info though.